# Repair of 320 kbps MP3 file recorded accidentally at maximum manual recording level setting

Tags: field-recording, levels

Question,

The Auto Level Control Slide Selector switch was accidendally bumped from Auto to Manual Recording Level Mode.

The manual level thumb dial was at 10.  On playback the there is a high level of background sound which all but covers over the faint voices in the mp3 file.  Speach barely intelligible about 25% of the time.

Is the a repair/restoration strategy that is known for such an issue that would leave voices intelligable and eleminate the rest of the interfering sounds.

I have used band pass filter leaing just 150 Hz-3,5kHZ, de-noise-declick, spectral sampling and removal with unacceptable results using 3 by consumer level editting package without success.

Any help on this one?

Answer (score 1):

There are some very good noise reduction processors available (my favourite is iZotope RX2 Advanced) although I'm afraid it sounds like your material may be beyond repair. 
If your voices are barely intelligible, you may even have a problem with the way it was mic'd.
If you had mics placed where you could here voices clearly, recording an overloaded signal won't diminish the voices into the background.
Anyway, sorry for the bad news. Better luck next time.

Cheers, Simon